# Need help to connect Unix through Excel

Tags: vba, excel, unix

As Part of data Analysis, I need to connect excel macros with unix, fire my shell script from a macro, and get the output file back to excel. I tried using winsock, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very clear question...
but i suggest to split the problem into parts

- test the shell script to make sure it outputs exactly what you want (including carriage returns / whitespace / other fromatting that might confuse Windows or Excel)
- test your method of connecting from Windows to Unix.  make sure you can run a command from PowerShell which logs in to the unix machine, runs the script, and returns the result
- test your Excel macro.  ensure it has permission to make the connection you made from PowerShell

You'll have better luck on StackOverflow if you post a piece of code (or network details) and the error message you got from that code.